# Is it bad practice to request up to 100 ajax requests on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a table that can show up to (or sometimes more) 100 rows.
Is it bad practice to loop through all these rows, firing off an AJAX post request to get data?
I don't want to do this through the page load as it would take forever to load the page (and the information that is shown is not always required to the user).

This obvioulsy fire off many different AJAX requests at the one time.. just wandering if this is a bad idea?

Comment: Would it not be possible to do it all in one request?

Comment: Not just a bad idea... it is a *really bad idea*. The browser will queue up requests beyond the first handful. Always batch large amounts of data in only a few requests as each request has a [relatively] large overhead.

Comment: How do you determine if it's "required to the user" and why can't you do that on the server just as easily as in the browser? If loading the required information on the server would make the page "take forever to load" then you're probably doing it incorrectly. Basically, what are you actually trying to achieve here? There's got to be a better/more efficient way to do it.

Comment: 5 downvotes? Geez can someone explain why? @AnthonyGrist- I can't determine if the user want's it or not- it is a list of orders and the tracking data for it (Carrier and Consignment number).

Comment: @Lock So why not have the tracking data in an expandable section underneath each row, and only request it when the user actually clicks to view it? Or just load all of that information along with the list of orders in one query when the page loads, doesn't seem like that should add much to how long it takes to load.

Answer (score 1):

Yes its bad idea .So Fire 1 ajax And then On Success of it bind records u got using jquery or angular js .Why ??

It will consume resources of server so there will be traffic problem,CPU load and lot more

Read more about AJAX optimization in this [Article](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/secrets/ajax/).

Comment: "Yes it's bad" is not an answer. Please also explain *why* is it a bad idea :)

Comment: So in another word can I assume "Sending one request per page will be best for binding" ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is bad for backend because takes extra resources to open connection etc for all requests and for frontend (browser) too. Bad idea. You can try and look at the CPU/Memory usage to get a picture.